# Limit string length with SED in bash

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I need delete words that do not meet string size conditions, in this case, that the string has more than 5 characters but less than 10.

I tried to

```
sed -ni '/{$carac1,$carac2}$/p' $1
```

where `carac1` is 5 and `carac2` is 10, but this didn't function.

Input:

```
asdasd
aswq
asfasfasgga
sgasgaga
wwqwe
```

output:

```
asdasd
sgasgaga
wwqwe
```

Comment: With GNU grep: `grep -E "^.{$carac1,$carac2}$" file`

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Comment: This delete all the file

Comment: Why is `wwqwe` in the output? Is doesn't have more than 5 characters. Or you mean "at least" and "at most", instead of "more than" and "less than"?

Comment: I think that 5 is the minimum length of characters and 10 the maximum, including both. It is somewhat less that, I can fix it easier, but the problem is the command that deletes the entire file.

Comment: My question is: is it "more/less than" or "more/less than or equal"? You write the first, but your attempt seems to imply the second.

Comment: Use `dos2unix < file | grep -E "^.{$carac1,$carac2}$"` to fix line breaks in your file.

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to use double quotes. Variables aren't expanded inside single quotes.

Second, you need to put something before `{min,max}`, to specify what should be matched that many times. Use `.` to match any character.

Third, you need to anchor it at the beginning of the line.

```
sed -rni "/^.{$carac1,$carac2}$/p" "$1"
```

You should also quote `$1` in case it contains spaces or wildcard characters.

Comment: Using sed -ni "^.{$carac1,$carac2}$/p" "$1" bash display an error, but if i use sed -ni "/^.{$carac1,$carac2}$/p" "$1" the command delete all the registres of the file

Comment: You need to use the `-r` option to use an extended regular expression, or escape the `{`